# Azure IoT Edge edgeHub module can't start

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-edge

I've successfully installed IoT edge runtime with system edgeAgent module. Now I'm trying to install SimulatedTemperatureSensor module as it is recommended in Microsoft [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/iot-edge/quickstart). I add this module from a market place and two new modules appear in Azure portal when I click submit: edgeHub and as expected SimulatedTemperatureSensor. After several seconds those modules appear on my device (my windows 10 based machine). Unfortunately, iotedge service can't start either of those modules. I'm receiving

> The password for this account has expired

error all the time as shown in logs below. I did the same couple of weeks ago on another machine and everything went perfectly well. Does anybody know what could cause this issue?

Logs:

```
info: edgelet_docker::runtime -- Starting module edgeHub...                                                
31/01/2019 4:39:31 PM  warn: edgelet_utils::logging -- Could not start module edgeHub                                             
31/01/2019 4:39:31 PM  warn: edgelet_utils::logging --  caused by: container                                                      
     2081f5de294aaad116fdac602db92cc316f5b88c7 encountered an error during               
     CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The password for this account has expired
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you also asked the question in the Edge GitHub but the same question was answered here: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/774#issuecomment-459279608

> Fix for this has been checked in and will be released very soon.
>
> Workaround in the time being is to change the “1.0” tag for the
>   edgeHub container image to “1.0.6-rc1” in deployment json.

Update: Final 1.0.6 has been released now: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iotedge/releases/tag/1.0.6

Comment: Yes, I've got this answer from Edge GitHub. Thanks